# Access HomeKit secure video list

Tags: video, homekit

I am looking for a way to get the list of HomeKit secure videos that are stored on iCloud.
The objective is to show a list of them, maybe with come information like person or animal identification.

I search the Apple doc for API but found nothing (I know the HomeKit doc, and have made several HomeKit apps already).

Can anybody point me to a documentation entry point, is that Apple reserved only ?